# jQuery CSS Attributes not Applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am centering a element inside a div horizontally and vertically, however the jQuery CSS code seems to be only resulting in `style="margin: 0px"` any ideas?

[Example](http://www.beeskneesfx.com/viewer.html?src=aHR0cDovL2ZjMDQuZGV2aWFudGFydC5uZXQvZnM3MC9mLzIwMTQvMjc5LzAvYy9kZXN0cm9pZF9ieV9iZnh3YWxrZXItZDgxdHBsbC5wbmc=&t=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5iZWVza25lZXNmeC5jb20vc2hvd3RocmVhZC5waHAvMzQ3LUxBLURlc3Ryb2lk)
(*[script src](http://beeskneesfx.com/js/bfx.viewer.js)*)

**jQuery:**

```
    image.css({
            'margin-top': '-'+(style['img-width']/2)+'px',
            'margin-left': '-'+(style['img-height']/2)+'px',
    });
```

*Alternatively I tried:*

```
    image.css({
            'marginTop': '-'+(style['img-width']/2)+'px',
            'marginLeft': '-'+(style['img-height']/2)+'px',
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
                #theater-img {
                    position: absolute;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                #theater-img img {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                }
```

Comment: You should be changing the values of `top` and `left` since your image is already on absolute position.

Comment: What is `image`? Is it constructed in jQuery? Do you get any console errors?

Comment: `image` is the image tag. It's used multiple times. I added a link to the src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the following line in your `bfx.viewer.js`:

`image.css('margin', style['img-padding']+'px');`

This is there the `margin: 0px;` comes from.

Comment: Ah jesus I forgot about that. Do you know why when I fix it, the image is pushed off screen on the top? It's acting like `#theater-img` is way off screen for the centering. See example link again.

Comment: I see you have changed your code radically :) At your current situation remove `position: relative` from the `theater-img` and it will be centered.

Answer (score 1):

I just commented below positioning CSS:

```
/*
#theater-img img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
*/
```

and then changed the postion to relative instead of absolute here:

```
#theater-img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Is it you wanted ??

[image: Page Image with updated css]

Answer (score 0):

I saw your example link. I think use that codes after all images loaded.

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function() {    
    $('#theater-img img').css({
        'margin-top': '-' + $('#theater-img img').height()/2 + 'px',
        'margin-left': '-' + $('#theater-img img').width()/2 + 'px'
    });
});
```

---

and here's some css changes for your page. You should change #theater-img

**HMTL:**

```
#theater-img {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 46px 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -46px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can use '$('img').load(function() {' instead of '$(window).load(function() {'

Comment: Why exactly am I hiding a portion of the image under the top bar? This is a image viewer. Also, `image` has already been defined, as the theater image..